# Measure amplitude of a sound wave

Tags: waves

I am trying to find out the amplitude of a sound wave. What equation or apparatus can I use to achieve this?

Comment: A microphone does this. What are you really trying to do? Can you be more explicit about your needs?

Comment: There is an app called "decibel 10th" that seems to be pretty comprehensive: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/decibel-10th/id448155923?mt=8

Comment: From their description: _"Decibel 10th turns your iPhone, iPad and iPod touch into a professional sound meter, precisely measures the sound pressure level all around you. This extremely useful and beautiful tool will not only be a great tool for many uses but also bring you a lot of fun. Have you wondered how quiet is your room or how loud is a rock concert or sport event? Decibel 10th will help you answer all those right now. "_